# LINQ List<> Moving Elements up and down

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Would it be possible to tell me the best way of moving elements in a `List<>` up and down.

For example I have a class called Building and Building has a list of Rooms objects `List<Room>`. The rooms are added to the building by name, but I am using this structure to generate a tree view. The user has the option to move a room up and down within a building.

I was trying to use `.Reverse(index, count)` but this didn't seem to do anything:

```
// can this item actually be moved up (is it at the first position in it's current parent?)
if (moveDirection == MoveDirection.UP)
{
    int roomIndex = parentBuilding.Rooms.IndexOf(room);

    if (roomIndex == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // move this room up.                            
        parentBuilding.Rooms.Reverse(roomIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reverse function returns an IEnumerable that is the oposite way of the list the function is used on. So the list itself will not be changed. You can use basic index replacement. Which is if you have two elements in a list and you want to move the second element, you store the first element in a temp variable and designate the second element to the first element, and then assign the second element to the temp variable.

Comment: WinForms or WPF? And how are you generating the `TreeView`?

Comment: Using MVC 3 with Razor and i'm building the tree view myself and using jQuery to expand and collapse the UL elements

Comment: What do you mean by "best" way? The fastest, the most correct, the quickest to implement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a list extension. Call as `List<T>.Move(1, MoveDirection.Up)`.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void Move<T>(this IList<T> list, int iIndexToMove, 
        MoveDirection direction)
    {

        if (direction == MoveDirection.Up)
        {
            var old = list[iIndexToMove - 1];
            list[iIndexToMove - 1] = list[iIndexToMove];
            list[iIndexToMove] = old;
        }
        else
        {
            var old = list[iIndexToMove + 1];
            list[iIndexToMove + 1] = list[iIndexToMove];
            list[iIndexToMove] = old;
        }
    }
}

public enum MoveDirection
{
    Up,
    Down
}
```

**Things to consider**

- Exception handling - what if you are trying to move the bottom
  element down or top element up? You will get an index out of range
  because you can't move these up or down.
- You could improve this and prevent handling exception by extending
  functionality to moving the top element to the bottom element and
  bottom element down to the top element etc.

Comment: Thanks I have used this example, I will check what the current Index is before I try and move the element.

Answer (score 4):

Just do a swap:

```
int roomIndex = parentBuilding.Rooms.IndexOf(room);

if (roomIndex == 0)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    // move this room up.                            
    var temp = parentBuilding.Rooms[index-1];
    parentBuilding.Rooms[index-1] = parentBuilding.Rooms[index];
    parentBuilding.Rooms[index] = temp;
}
```

Comment: You appear to have sawped some letters in your text.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd make extension method:

```
static void Swap<TSource>(this IList<TSource> source, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullExcpetion("source");

    TSource tmp = source[toIndex];
    source[toIndex] = source[fromIndex];
    source[fromIndex] = tmp;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (moveDirection == MoveDirection.UP)
{
    int roomIndex = parentBuilding.Rooms.IndexOf(room);

    if (roomIndex == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // move this room up.                            
        parentBuilding.Rooms.Swap(roomIndex, roomIndex - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `SortedDictionary<int, Room>` instead of a list. You could store an index in as a Key of the Dictionary and just swap the values when needed.

Comment: You can't rely on a Dictionary<K,V> to return the contents in the order specified by the key. The dictionary uses a hash table internally.

Comment: Now it will return them in the right order, but you can't change the key without removing/reinserting the values, which is not efficient.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde I wrote nothing about removing and reinserting. I mentioned swapping the values like this: 

  var temp = dictionary[index];
  dictionary[index] = dictionary[index+1] ;
  dictionary[index + 1] = temp;

Comment: Then why are you using a dictionary?

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde because sorted dictionary is more expressive about the requirement specified in the question. My opinion of course.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde this conversation has become meaningless for some time now. The last thing on my agenda was to convince you to remove the downvote. You asked the questions, I answered them. If I wanted to get back my two points of reputation, it would be just as easy as deleting my post. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: SortedDictionary is less expressive than List, because a SortedDictionary sorts the sequence for you, while with a List you make it clear that the order set by the caller must be preserved. Other than that, it's less efficient, although in this case the efficiency of the data structure is the least concern. Better?

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde GwynnBleidd is right of course, no need to argue +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

Swapping places with the room that used to be above should do it:

```
int roomIndex = parentBuilding.Rooms.IndexOf(room);

if (roomIndex == 0)
{
    return;
}

var wasAbove = parentBuilding.Rooms[roomIndex - 1];
parentBuilding.Rooms[roomIndex - 1] = room;
parentBuilding.Rooms[roomIndex] = wasAbove;
```

That said, I 'm not sure that this is the best object model for the situation; it's not clear that the order of rooms in the list plays a role, and it's also not clear how a room can be "moved up" -- what does that mean?

It might be better to have a `RoomPlacement` class that aggregates a room and enough information to locate it, and work with that instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int newIndex = whateverIndexYouWantItAt;

int oldIndex = parentBuilding.Rooms.IndexOf(room);
var item = parentBuilding.Rooms[oldIndex];

list.RemoveAt(oldIndex);

if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex--; 

parentBuilding.Rooms.Insert(newIndex, item);
```

Comment: I think inserting and removing from a list is not efficient. I think it's better to swap the values instead, and keep the list at the same size the whole time.

Comment: so if you want it to move one place up you would just make `newIndex = oldIndex - 1;` I guess