# Does code exist, for shifting List elements to left or right by specified amount, in C#?

Tags: c#

Does code exist, for shifting List elements to left or right by specified amount, in C#?

It is tricky code, it will take some time to write and test special cases, I would rather
reuse something if it exists.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean shift? Pad strings (list elements) Left/Right? Order a list?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the shifting that you're trying to achieve? Is this "reassign the indexes of all of the elements in the list, such that `list[0]` returns what was `list[1]`, etc" or "for each element *in* the list, perform some shift operation upon it"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133577/linq-list-moving-elements-up-and-down

Comment: I think `list.Insert(index, item)` is the way to go

Comment: What list implementation are you using? Linked list can easily be "shifted", shifting an array backed "list" like `List` is rather expensive - but both is actually really simple..

Comment: Does not matter. I can easily transfer to array or list whatever I like.

Comment: The definition of shift: "move (data) one or more places to the right or left in a register." Is that not explicitly obvious? He's obviously not talking about a linked list or B-tree or red-black tree or anything else more obviously complicated than a "List" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C#.  Y'all need to study more group theory.

Comment: @JoePhillips I was commenting on the fact that the OP is asking a simple question about a specific data type in C# that people are making complicated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this for shift left...

```
public static void ShiftLeft<T>(List<T> lst, int shifts)
{
    for (int i = shifts; i < lst.Count; i++)
    {
        lst[i - shifts] = lst[i];
    }

    for (int i = lst.Count - shifts; i < lst.Count; i++)
    {
        lst[i] = default(T);
    }
}
```

For shift right it's a little more tricky, because we must copy in reverse

```
public static void ShiftRight<T>(List<T> lst, int shifts)
{
    for (int i = lst.Count - shifts - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        lst[i + shifts] = lst[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < shifts; i++)
    {
        lst[i] = default(T);
    }
}
```

With arrays it's a lot more simple, because `Array` has very powerful methods:

```
public static void ShiftLeft<T>(T[] arr, int shifts)
{
    Array.Copy(arr, shifts, arr, 0, arr.Length - shifts);
    Array.Clear(arr, arr.Length - shifts, shifts);
}

public static void ShiftRight<T>(T[] arr, int shifts)
{
    Array.Copy(arr, 0, arr, shifts, arr.Length - shifts);
    Array.Clear(arr, 0, shifts);
}
```

And yes, `Array.Copy` *is* protected against overleap: [If sourceArray and destinationArray overlap, this method behaves as if the original values of sourceArray were preserved in a temporary location before destinationArray is overwritten.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/z50k9bft.aspx)

Comment: @hvd http://stackoverflow.com/a/2381397/613130 Someone benchmarked them... `Array.Copy` is faster (or at least it was). `Array.ConstrainedCopy` *Guarantees that all changes are undone if the copy does not succeed completely.* I'll say that must have a little cost.

Comment: @hvd He tested only on `int?`. Perhaps it depends on the type (you would have to test at least `byte`, `int`, `int?`, `DateTime`, `Guid`, `object`, (random object) to be sure... And in various sizes... 1, 16, 100, 1000, 10000.) In the end probably the difference is nearly 0.

Comment: I was going to ask why these were not extension methods, but then I saw the code below.

Comment: instead of filling the range [lst.Count - shifts, lst.Count ) with default(T), I'm going to set the list Count to (Count - shifts), and I will leave the Capacity untouched since my list can grow again !

Comment: Argh, it's not like C++, I will use RemoveRange instead !

Answer (score 11):

Below are a couple of extension methods that will shift the list either right or left.  The methods will return a list.

```
public static class ShiftList
{
    public static List<T> ShiftLeft<T>(this List<T> list, int shiftBy)
    {
        if (list.Count <= shiftBy)
        {
            return list;
        }

        var result = list.GetRange(shiftBy, list.Count-shiftBy);
        result.AddRange(list.GetRange(0,shiftBy));
        return result;
    }

    public static List<T> ShiftRight<T>(this List<T> list, int shiftBy)
    {
        if (list.Count <= shiftBy)
        {
            return list;
        }

        var result = list.GetRange(list.Count - shiftBy, shiftBy);
        result.AddRange(list.GetRange(0, list.Count - shiftBy));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how to call it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> test = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
        test = test.ShiftLeft(1);

        PrintList(test);
        Console.WriteLine("");

        PrintList(test.ShiftRight(2));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintList(List<int> test)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like nerdybeardo posted, but a modern way:

```
public static class ShiftList
{
    public static List<T> ShiftLeft<T>(this List<T> list, int shiftBy)
    {
        if (list.Count <= shiftBy)
        {
            return list;
        }

        return list.Skip(shiftBy).Concat(list.Take(shiftBy)).ToList();
    }

    public static List<T> ShiftRight<T>(this List<T> list, int shiftBy)
    {
        if (list.Count <= shiftBy)
        {
            return list;
        }

        return list.ShiftLeft(list.Count - shiftBy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple by taking the first part and second part and flipping them. Same thing but flip other way for the ShiftRight

```
    public static List<int> ShiftLeft(List<int> a, int d)
    {
        if (a.Count > d)
        {
            var beginingPart = a.GetRange(0, d);
            var remainingPart = a.GetRange(d, a.Count - d);
            return remainingPart.Concat(beginingPart).ToList();
        }
        else if (a.Count < d)
        {
            var mod = d % a.Count;
            if (mod != 0)
            {
                return rotLeft(a, mod);
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a similar code snippet, can you tell me which user has similar? Also I'm not sure what question 2 is, I only see one question mark in the op post.  

If you mean nerdybeardo post, some parts are similar but mine uses recursion and handles an edge case that his doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Given that "iterations" is the times you want to shift and "numbers" is the List

Shift left:

```
static void ShiftLeft(int iterations)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(numbers[0]);
            numbers.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
```

ShiftRight:

```
static void ShiftRight(int iterations)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            numbers.Insert(0, numbers[numbers.Count - 1]);
            numbers.RemoveAt(numbers.Count - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is simple code but have you considered the performance implications? Each call to `RemoveAt()`/`Insert()` causes the rest of the list to be shifted 1 element, and you're passing the worst case, index `0`.  If `iterations` is `1000` then instead of shifting each element by 1,000 positions 1 time this will shift each element by 1 position 1,000 times; more shifts are expensive, bigger shifts are not/free. Also, if `numbers.Count == numbers.Capacity` this will cause the internal array to be resized (doubled) just to hold that one extra element that exists before `RemoveAt()` is called.